# How can I write perfectly centered tex inside a cloud figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a cloud with text inside using this guide (https://latexdraw.com/cloud-shape-in-tikz/).

```tex
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width=0.55cm,text centered]
    [execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{8pt},
        cloud,
        draw] (c) at (0,0)
    {\scriptsize{Lost\\Broker}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

its output

[image]

Here as you can see `Golden` part i not perfectly centered, should be shift little bit right. I have used `text centered`, which did not helped.

Is it possible to aligh the text perfectly in center?

wanted text should be:

```bash
  TeX   
 Golden // shifted 1 character to left
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce the `inner sep` and raise your `text width`.

[image: center text in cloud node]

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width=0.8cm,inner sep=0pt]
    [execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{8pt},
        cloud,
        draw] (c) at (0,0)
    {\scriptsize{Lost\\Broker}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer :-)

Comment: [align=center] makes [text width=...] redundant.  Basically you are putting a tabular inside a \parbox.

Comment: You'r right, I'm not familiar with those *lower* properties. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @SebGlav I have asked another question related to your answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650114/how-can-i-wrap-a-text-in-a-rectange-inside-a-cloud . Its kind of simple I just want to wrap the text inside a rectangle if possible