# How can I wrap a text in a rectange inside a cloud?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using code in the following solution [How can I write perfectly centered tex inside a cloud figure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/649479/127048):

> ```tex
> \documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
> \usepackage{tikz}
> \usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
> \begin{document}
> \begin{tikzpicture}
>    \node[text width=0.8cm,inner sep=0pt]
>    [execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{8pt},
>        cloud,
>        draw] (c) at (0,0)
>    {\scriptsize{Lost\\Broker}};
> \end{tikzpicture}
> \end{document}
> ```

---

I want to draw additional aligned rectange inside the cloud. Is it possible to wrap text inside the cloud with a rectangle as below, filling inside with gray if possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An other approach using tikz library `fit`: a cloud node fit to the size of a rectangle node

```tex
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols, fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[text width=0.8cm, inner sep=1pt, fill=gray!50]
        [node font=\setlength{\baselineskip}{8pt}\scriptsize, draw] 
      (c) at (0,0)
      {Lost\\ Broker};
    \node[draw, cloud, inner sep=-1pt, fit=(c)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: To color (fill) the cloud:

```tex
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, shapes.symbols, fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[text width=0.8cm, inner sep=1pt, fill=gray!50]
       [node font=\setlength{\baselineskip}{8pt}\scriptsize, draw] 
    (c) at (0,0) {Lost\\ Broker};
  \scoped[on background layer]
    \node[draw, cloud, inner sep=-1pt, fit=(c), fill=cyan!30] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: cloud with light blue background color]

Comment: if I use `\textbf{Broker}` instead of `Broker` it exceeds the rectange is it possible to make rectange align for the bolded text as well?

Comment: Is it also possible to label cloud node? When I draw arrows into `c` it does not draw starting from the cloud

Comment: @alper Replace `text width=0.8cm` with `align=left`. But then you lose auto linebreaks.

Comment: @alper Yes you can name the fit node, for example `\node[..., fit=(c)] (c') {};` then use `c'` in following drawing.

Comment: sorry for the late question, is it possible to color the cloud at the background?

Comment: @alper See update.

Comment: Image server had problems. Is up and running now. You may want to try to upload the image again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a label like this

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[cloud, draw, text width=0.6cm, label={[draw, text width=0.8cm, inner sep=2pt, font=\scriptsize]center:{Lost\\Broker}}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Text within rectangle within cloud shape]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[cloud, fill=cyan, draw, text width=0.6cm, label={[draw, fill=pink, text width=0.8cm, inner sep=2pt, font=\scriptsize]center:{Lost\\Broker}}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Cyan and pink cloud]

Comment: Is it possible to fill color inside of the rectangle?

Comment: Yes - just add `fill=...`

Comment: I'd do `\node[cloud, fill=cyan, draw, node font=\scriptsize, align=center, label={[draw, fill=pink, node font=\scriptsize, align=center]center:{Lost\\Broker}}] {\phantom{Lost}\\\phantom{Broker}};` so that there's no fiddling needed with `text width` because the `cloud` will be automatically big enough for the label to fit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `\fcolorbox`. This does not allow line breaks though, for that you can put the text inside a `\parbox`. You may need to play with the box width (`9mm` in the MWE) to get the correct line break.

Note also that `\scriptsize` is not a command that takes an argument, it is a switch that changes the font size until a new font size command is found or until the group ends. So the correct syntax is `\scriptsize Some text` and *not* `\scriptsize{Some text}`.

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[inner sep=0pt,cloud,draw] (c) at (0,0)
   {\fcolorbox{black}{gray}{\parbox{9mm}{\scriptsize Lost Broker}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to force the text to be centered as well?

Comment: Yes, with `\parbox{9mm}{\centering\scriptsize Lost Broker}`